# HTML & CSS: Dragging and drop in multiple directions

Tags: javascript, css, html

So far I have managed to implement a simple drag and drop feature. It allows the user to drag the image from one div into another div. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> The New Dashboard </title>
        <style>

            #div1 {width:1000px;height:500px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
            #top {width:1000px;height:100px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa}

        </style>
        <script>
            function allowDrop(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();

            }
            function drag(ev){

                ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }
            function drop(ev){

                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

            }
        </script>
    </head>



    <body>

        <div id = "top" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event">

            <img id = "drag1" src="slwheel.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </div>


        <div id = "div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">


        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

So now I want to drag the slwheel image from its new location in the #div1 div back into the #top div, but it does not let me do so. What am I doing wrong? Any help can be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis at the end of ondragover, in the first div

Comment: Thanks. That did it. What a terrible rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In top div you miss ) in allowDrop(event)

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing ) in the "top" div that would not make my code work. Complete rookie mistake. My sincerest apologies.